# angular filter on multiple arguments from one object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object in angularjs `reportViewList`, which has two members: `name` and `bpList`. `bpList` is also an object with two elements: `id` and `name`.

Assume I have an input with ng-model reportFilter and I want to show the results by the uniion of name and `bpList.name`.

I wrote the codes as follows:

```
ng-repeat="view in reportViewList | filter:( {name: reportFilter}||{bpList.name: reportFilter} )"
```

But, the sentence after opeartion `||` doesn't work.

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Can you post your filter code or create a plunker with some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-repeat="view in reportViewList | filter:reportFilter"
```

will match if name has substring reportFilter or bpList.name has substring reportFilter

```
ng-repeat="view in reportViewList | filter:{name:reportFilter, bpList.name:reportFilter}"
```

will match if both name and bpList.name have substring reportFilter

Comment: But if I input some number into it, bpLists with same id will be returned.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Where do you input some number? It's best if you provide a plunker that demonstrates the problem you have.